# How can I limit a count of reregistrations in Asterisk PJSIP?

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

**Asterisk 16 + Pjsip realtime**

Hello. 
When someone connects with wrong password, I have a flood of error messages in Asterisk cli (~20 messages per second). I remember, in sip I could limit reregistrations and timeout with two parametres: registertimeout and registerattempts. But how can I do it with PJSIP?
I have read manual and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PJSIP should not deal with it, so there are no way do it via PJSIP.

You have read about fail2ban/iptables.